# Run task every minute in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm very beginner in mobile development.
I want to create an android app with flutter which send a GET request to my server every minutes even if the app is in background or screen is off. I did it with the Cron plugin but when the app is no more in foreground, the data are not sent to my server.
Can you please help me to know which plugin need I to use ?
I tried with android_workmanager_plus but periodically wasn't seem to work :/

this is how it's implemented for the moment

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var cron =  Cron();
                  cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('*/1 * * * *'), () async {
                  BlocProvider.of<TestCubit>(context).validate();
                  });
                },
```

and this is my method in my cubit file

```
validate() async{

    var battery = Battery();
    var batlevel = await battery.batteryLevel;
    state.status = Colors.blue;
    emit(state);
    try{
      final batt = await repo.getBattery(batlevel.toString());
      print(batt);
      //print(state.path);

    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    state.status = Colors.green;
    emit(state);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your future help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugins to repeat something every second, however I doubt this works when the app is not open, it works when the app is open and backgrounded

```
t = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) => yourFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dart:async` in your code with `Timer.periodic`

ex: for run task every 60 seconds

```dart
timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(
        seconds: 60, //You can change second to milisecond etc
      ),
      (t) => getData(),
    );
```

you can add it in function or in initstate, [Docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html)

Nb: don't forget to add
`import 'dart:async';` and `late Timer timer;`

Comment: Yes I used it but only in foreground, but when screen is off it doesn't work.
Do you think using multiple periodic task in Workmanager could send data every minutes ? With 15 same callbacks ?

Comment: I had the issue in opposite, using workmanager, my data fetching service was running consistently in the background, but not in the foreground. Although Android workmanager should support tasks in both backgrounds and foreground. The only caviate is maybe when the device is in the recent mode in Android.
Not sure about iOS, I don't currently have a macOS to target iOS.